Controller parameter annotated with [FromBody] is null after Ajax POST to controller
I have a controller method that expects as a parameter a model type. I am using Ajax to POST data to this controller method.
public async Task<ActionResult> EditMessageEffectiveDate([FromBody] Models.ViewModels.UserWarningMsg msg){ ... }

I've set a breakpoint at the beginning of this controller method's body and see that the msg object is always null after Ajax posts data to it.
function onEditEffectiveDate(e) {
    var grid = $("#WarningMessagesGrid").data("kendoGrid");
    var tr = $(e.target).closest("tr");
    var targetRow = grid.dataItem(tr);

    console.log(JSON.stringify(targetRow)); // SEE BELOW

    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '@Url.Action("EditMessageEffectiveDate", "UserWarningMessages")',
        contentType: "application/json;",
        dataType: "json",
        data: { 'msg': JSON.stringify(targetRow) },
        success: function (data) { ... }
    });


console.log(JSON.stringify(targetRow)); outputs the following:
{ "Param1":"123ABC",
"Param2":"1995-01-01T20:00:00.000Z",
"Param3":1,
"Param4":"PARAM",
"Param5":"PARAM",
"Param6":"",
"Param7":"+010000-01-01T01:00:00.000Z",
"Param8":"" }

The model used to bind the posted data is as follows:
    public class UserWarningMsg
    {
        public string? Param1 { get; set; }

        [DataType(DataType.Date)]
        public DateTime Param2 { get; set; }

        public int Param3 { get; set; }

        public string? Param4 { get; set; }

        public string? Param5 { get; set; }

        public string? Param6 { get; set; }

        public DateTime Param7 { get; set; }

        public string? Param8 { get; set; }
    }

There are dozens of similar posts. Here is what I have tried so far:

Removing the contentType and dataType attributes in the Ajax call (individually and collectively)

Annotating the controller method with [HttpPost]

Removing the FromBody parameter annotation

Skipping the call to JSON.stringify() and sending the object directly

Replacing data: { 'msg': JSON.stringify(targetRow) }, with data: JSON.stringify(targetRow), or data: targetRow,

Constructing an object from targetRow field by field:


        var msgObject = {};
        msgObject.Param1= targetRow['Param1'];
        msgObject.Param2 = targetRow['Param2'];
        msgObject.Param3 = targetRow['Param3'];
        ...
        $ajax({ 
            ...
            data: JSON.stringify(msgObject); // also tried without stringify 
            ...
        )};

All of these approaches either didn't result in a non-null object being received by the controller or resulted in errors.
Elsewhere in this same application I have used an identical approach. Can anyone see why the model binding is failing and msg is null in my controller method?

The model binding was not working as it can't deserialize Param7. "Param7":"+010000-01-01T01:00:00.000Z", the ISO8601 date format is incorrect. You can try not to pass the Param7 from ajax or temporary comment the Param7 property in the model and it will work.

Besides, use data: JSON.stringify(targetRow)

I've updated my model to allow null DateTime types:  public DateTime? Param7 and have removed the problematic field from targetRow before posting with Ajax: delete targetRow['Param7] but the object is still received as null.

Hmmm, that's weird, can you capture the request headers, payload sent in the browser DevTools?
